Find specific rule in iptables reported by trace
I'm trying to troubleshoot a firewall rule causing packets to drop.
I set up TRACE and got the following:
 TRACE: 1 79de9f86 filter:input:rule:0x17:DROP  

How do I find which specific rule is referenced and causing the dropped packets?

Ubuntu is now using 'nft', not iptables.
#nft monitor trace

showed which table and rule was causing the drop.
